# $t \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(t)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x^t) \ dx, t\in\mathbb{R}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

> $$f(t)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x^t) \ dx, t\in\mathbb{R}$$

I need to find out for which $t \in \mathbb{R}$ this integrals exists (meaning it doesn't diverge) as Riemann-integral at first and then as Lebesgue-integral.

Comment: Use the substitution $u=x^t$, $u^{\frac{1}{t}}=x$, $\frac{du u^{\frac{1}{t}-1}}{t}=dx$